# Node-PostgresQL - 42P01 - "Table" Relation Does Not Exist - In Independent File

Tags: node.js, postgresql

Hope you're well. I have seen a number of questions out there that have a similar source to my own, but I have not found any that I can identify as having the same factors. It is for this reason I am posting my question. I will mention the posts I reviewed as I go, so if I missed something hopefully someone can inform me.

I'm obviously being told that a relation does not exist. I'm not sure what it is in relation to, as the table in question is referred to twice in my select query. Once in a join, once in a subquery. In either case, I know the relation exists so the computer is just wrong. Not only that, but I have executed the query within a different module of my application, and it executes - which I believe is important.

Here are some relevant preliminaries.

1. I am attempting to set up a scheduled task to send out e-mails after a delayed interval. The relevant information about the emails is going to come from the database as called by this query.
2. Currently, the last step I have in that process is to ensure that I can run the module in question from the command line, so I can schedule the task to fire. After that, I set up the command line task in heroku scheduler.
3. I have confirmed the query works, within the context of an express function enclosing it - I want the independent module to just run the query w/out express (if possible.) I've seen it execute this exact way on other peoples files, so I don't know why it is not working for me when I mimic their code.
4. The query works *both* within the express function mentioned above, and when I run it within the postgresQL db. The query is indisputably syntactically correct, because I've used it in multiple contexts and it works.

Some questions I think you'll have:

A.) **[Is there a casing issue in reference to the tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39783836/unable-to-query-postgresql-database-in-nodejs-using-pg-promise-relation-does)** No, I don't know how that could be possible. The same exact query worked within a different module of the application.

B.) **Have you tried referencing the database/schema name as a preface to the relation error?** Yes. **Does that query you tried still work in different contexts?** Yes.

C.) **Have you tried creating different aliases for the subquery and the join?** Yes. I did this both with and without the database/schema attached to them. This query works outside of the context I'm having the issue with it in.

D.) **Is it possible that the table somehow does not exist at the time the query is run?** The table definitely exists. My best hunch is, is that for some reason the module I'm trying to run the database query from is not accessing the db schema in question but the other file is.

E.) **[Is there some kind of public/private schema issue going on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47270100/error-42p01-relation-does-not-exist-non-public-schema-in-postgresql)?** No. All tables are public.

F.) **[Is this a temporary table or something?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54212063/sql-error-42p01-error-relation-temp-table-name-does-not-exist)** No.

G.) **Can you let me see the database schema?** [Right here](https://newtextdocument.com/62f896b80d)

I hope this was all helpful, as it appears to me that this question gets asked a lot and a lot of people don't like repetition on here, and I try my best to respect that.

usually when I have database activity going on, I don't separate it into independent modules like this, but keep it concentrated into a single file. I've never divided it up like this before. I mention this because that may imply there is some other arrangement for the application I need to make but am not aware of.

I hope all the information I have provided you with will help you in answering.

Below is the independent module in which the code is contained which creates the error. There is a second block of code - that block of code is the context in which it worked. This is as mentioned before, in a different module/file. That module contains many other express/db queries as well. They all work.:

**Block 1 - Independent Module**

```
const db = new pg.Pool({
  connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
  ssl: { rejectUnauthorized: false }
});

const sqlEmailGetQuery = `select DISTINCT on ("f"."flightId") "f"."flightName" as "flightName", "s"."scriptName", "e"."subject", "e"."emailBody",
                            (select json_agg (json_build_object('firstName', "c"."firstName", 'lastName', "c"."lastName", 'company',"c"."company", 'email', "c"."email"))
                              from "contacts" as "c"
                              inner join "flightAssignments" as "fas" on "c"."contactId" = "fas"."contactId"
                              )
                            from "flightAssignments" as "fA"
                            join "contacts" as "c" on "fA"."contactId" = "c"."contactId"
                            inner join "flights" as "f" on "fA"."flightId" = "f"."flightId"
                            inner join "scripts" as "s" on "f"."scriptId" = "s"."scriptId"
                            inner join "emails" as "e" on "s"."scriptId" = "e"."scriptId"
                            where "e"."sendOn" > now() and "e"."sendOn" is NOT NULL`;
db.query(sqlEmailGetQuery)
  .then(result => {
    const flightInfo = result.rows[0];
    handleEmail(flightInfo);
  }).catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
  });
```

**Block 2 - Working: Express w/ defined route.**

```
app.get('/api/sendAll/allEmails', (request, response) => {
const sqlEmailGetQuery = `select DISTINCT on ("f"."flightId") "f"."flightName" as "flightName", "s"."scriptName", "e"."subject", "e"."emailBody",
                            (select json_agg (json_build_object('firstName', "c"."firstName", 'lastName', "c"."lastName", 'company',"c"."company", 'email', "c"."email"))
                              from "contacts" as "c"
                              inner join "flightAssignments" as "fas" on "c"."contactId" = "fas"."contactId"
                              )
                            from "flightAssignments" as "fA"
                            join "contacts" as "c" on "fA"."contactId" = "c"."contactId"
                            inner join "flights" as "f" on "fA"."flightId" = "f"."flightId"
                            inner join "scripts" as "s" on "f"."scriptId" = "s"."scriptId"
                            inner join "emails" as "e" on "s"."scriptId" = "e"."scriptId"
                            where "e"."sendOn" > now() and "e"."sendOn" is NOT NULL`;
  db.query(sqlEmailGetQuery)
    .then(result => {
      const flightInfo = result.rows[0];
      handleEmail(flightInfo);
    }).catch(error => {
      console.error(error);
      response.status(500).json({ error: 'an unexpected error occured.' });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Never assume that the computer made a mistake; usually the mistake is yours.

In this case, there are a number of possible explanations:

- you connect to the wrong database
- you don't have the schema that contains the table in your `search_path` (in that case, the solution is to use `schemaname.tablename`)
- you created the table with upper case letters and double quotes (`"Table"`) but use it without (`Table`) or vice versa

Comment: Hi Laurenz, thank you for replying. I made the comment about the computer being wrong in frustration .

I don't mean to be rude, but I think if you take time to read the entire post, you'll see that I've tried all these things already. Are there any other possible issues it could be?

Comment: This is one of the most frequent complaints, and the cause is always a trivial one like I mentioned. In most cases, the problem would not exist if people didn't use upper case characters in their object names. I didn't mean to insult your intelligence, but connecting to the wrong database by mistake has happened to me too.

Comment: Laurenz, if you review the post you'll see I've been through all those. Thank you for your time though. I appreciate the effort.